# Using jQuery fade in/out with zClip (Flash)

Tags: jquery, flash, fadein, zclip

We've been building a CSS generator and want to have the ability to copy code. I'm calling the Flash code after the fade in, so there shouldn't be an issue with the display:none; stuff with Flash.

On the site I've been working on it on, if you go into [Firebug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firebug) then you can actually see the [zClip](http://www.steamdev.com/zclip/) `div` beneath the code, and if you press on it in Firebug, it suddenly activates for no obvious reason.

I have put it onto [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), and the activity I mentioned in the paragraph above doesn't occur at all. The zClip `div` just doesn't show. The jsFiddle link is http://jsfiddle.net/VFQDg/.

Comment: The reason this isn't working to show on JSFiddle is because the zclip plugin isn't included in the fiddle. Do you have the main page where I could look at this interaction?

Comment: Good timing for your response! I actually got it working for a few months. One day I then decided to do an upgrade. And despite the flash still loading - but doesn't actually copy anymore. This is the link to the page anyhow: http://joomjunk.co.uk/extras/css3-generator.html#border-radius

Comment: In which file are you binding .zclip?

Comment: in the modules default.php file (as it is a joomla module). The same as which the div is on. If you right click on the copy button you can see that the flash is being associated with the `div` element.

Comment: So are you binding the `.zclip()` method in the PHP template file? If I were you, I'd bring it out of there and have an event binding run after the `fadeIn()`. (I don't have access to the PHP file to actually see how it's being done).

Comment: I tried that intitially - but I found then the `.zclip` method didn't bind at all if not done on page load. Perhaps because of the swf file needing to be attached to the element? I should probably add that my latest issue with this means none of the copy buttons work at all. So its no longer a issue with the fade in I think.

Comment: You should probably post a new thread for that issue.

Comment: well this thread is like 6 months old :P i wasn't really expecting anyone to post on it after this amount of time lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for closure. I eventually got this fixed after several weeks of attempts. Still not 100% sure what I did though!

A note that my jsfiddle link missed the zclip jQuery file and works otherwise. Thanks to Andrew for pointing that out!